# How to embed the code of ArcGIS webapp builder into my Vue project

Tags: vue.js

How to embed the code of ArcGIS webapp builder into my Vue project

I placed the downloaded code provided in ArcGIS online in the Vue project, and my project directly started with an error message indicating a memory leak

Comment: Could you show an example of your code, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.